# What do I do with the egg that contains a crack while curing in brine?

Tags: eggs, food-preservation, salt, brining, curing

I am making some salted eggs using a saturated brine solution. I just noticed one of the eggs has crack in it. Should I be worried? The recipe instruction says I should check if one of the eggs have a crack but did not specify why or what to do with it.

Comment: no experience with this but if your instructions say to check for eggs with cracks I would take that to mean don't use that egg.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions mean that the quality, safety, or both, will suffer when you use cracked eggs. You are expected to throw the cracked eggs out and go on with the whole ones.

Comment: Add, when I did salted eggs, my instructions were to promptly remove any that cracked.  Early in the process, cracked can readily contaminate the brine and spoil ruining the entire batch.  On the surface, you would think the brine is strong enough to prevent this, but experience says that any leakage tends to float up which allows air contact and spoilage that can spread even through the brine.